# Double.Parse(string) not working correct when device language is not english monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have this code in my android application:

```
double lat = Double.Parse (latCoordinate);
```

When device language is english every thing is right, but when I select other languages it is not working.

In some languages it say that char '.' is not valid. An in some others parser the double string bad.for example parse "-95.22222" tp -9.522222 .

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Ouch, looks like you got smacked in the face by the Locale bug. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721950/double-parse-internationalization-problem)

Comment: Maybe answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477995/locale-independent-string-to-double

Comment: @Shark - What is the bug?  That link doesn't indicate that there is a bug with using different locales.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Some people write one thousand like this, some write em like `1,000`, some as `1000` and some as `1.000` or even `one-thousand` and all three have to be identical, programatically. All three are different under different Locales. It's not quite a bug, but it's far from desired behaviour. The link I posted contains a workaround on how to use the `Double.Parse` and get desired behaviour :)

Comment: @Shark - Your first comment seemed to indicate that there might be a bug in Double.Parse.  I see now, that the "bug" you referred to was actually in the user's code.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I was under the impression (or a bad habit) that this category of bugs are all dubbed "Locale bug". I had no intention of misleading that the bug is in `Double.Parse` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set cultureInfo to en-us like below:

```
return d.ToString (new CultureInfo ("en-US"));
```